# How can I convert japanese characters to unicode in Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode

Can you point me tool to convert japanese characters to unicode?

Comment: You mean from an Asian character set.  You need to find out what character encoding the Japanese is before you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPAN gives me "[Unicode::Japanese](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode::Japanese)". Hope this is helpful to start with. Also you can look at article on [Character Encodings in Perl](http://perlgeek.de/en/article/encodings-and-unicode) and perl doc for [unicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html#Unicode) for more information.

Comment: Why -ve? is that only for spell mistake :).

Answer (score 1):

See http://p3rl.org/UNI.

```
use Encode qw(decode encode);
my $bytes_in_sjis_encoding = "\x88\xea\x93\xf1\x8e\x4f";
my $unicode_string = decode('Shift_JIS', $bytes_in_sjis_encoding); # returns 一二三
my $bytes_in_utf8_encoding = encode('UTF-8', $unicode_string); # returns "\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xba\x8c\xe4\xb8\x89"
```

For batch conversion from the command line, use [piconv](http://perldoc.perl.org/piconv.html):

```
piconv -f Shift_JIS -t UTF-8 < infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find out the encoding of the source text if you don't know it already.

The most common encodings for Japanese are:

1. [`euc-jp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code): (often used on Unixes and some web pages etc with greater [Kanji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji) coverage than `shift-jis`)
2. [`shift-jis`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) (Microsoft also added some extensions to shift-jis which is called [`cp932`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932), which is often used on non-Unicode Windows programs)
3. [`iso-2022-jp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022) is a distant third

A common encoding conversion library for many languages is `iconv` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv and http://search.cpan.org/~mpiotr/Text-Iconv-1.7/Iconv.pm) which supports [many other encodings](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) as well as Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems a bit vague to me, I'm not sure what you're asking. Usually you would use something like this:

```
open my $file, "<:encoding(cp-932)", "JapaneseFile.txt"
```

to open a file with Japanese characters. Then Perl will automatically convert it into its internal Unicode format.